# How to navigate from FragmentA to FragmentB in viewPager from FragmentA class?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have a viewPager in `MainActivity` and have 2 fragments `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo`. In my `FragmentOne` I have a button that suppose to redirect user and open `FragmentTwo`. I know how to make it from parent `MainActivity`. But the trigger happens in `FragmentOne`. So how to achieve that directly from `FragmentOne` to `FragmentTwo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a public function in `MainActivity` that navigate from `FragmentOne` to `FragmentTwo` then get `MainActivity` in `FragmentOne` and call that function, so your code in `FragmentOne` should look like this:

```
(requireActivity() as AuthActivity).navigateFromFragmentAToFragmentB()
```

And in your activity you need to create that public function named `navigateFromFragmentAToFragmentB` that will navigate from `FragmentOne` to `FragmentTwo`

Comment: Is there a way to add code if we need to call in FragmentOne function from FragmentTwo?

Comment: Well, this is not possible, but you can use shared view model to communicate between the two fragments, see this link https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing